# Datatable not updating after delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am having trouble with my datatable, at the moment my datatable is populated with values from my database. When i upload a new file into the database, my datatable would automatically update and show what it has been updated with. But now i have a button which deletes a record from the database which is in correlation with the datatable that i have. The problem right now is that after i have deleted the record, the datatable is not refreshing and it still shows the record there. I have verified that the record has been deleted, its just that my datatable wont update.(It will only update after i refreshed the page). Below are my codes for the datatable, and delete button

Data Table:

```
<asp:GridView ID="FileTableView" CssClass="datagrid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="datagridHeader" RowStyle-CssClass="datagridRows" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="fileid, filename">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Master Folder">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="FileLinkButton" CommandName="ShowPopup" OnCommand="File_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("fileid") %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("filename") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Filling data into the datatable

```
DataTable dtFile;    
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Fill up file and folder data on the display
        FillDataFile();                                     
    }
}

private void FillDataFile()
{           
    dtFile = new DataTable();
    SqlDataReader reader = MBFile.GetFileToDisplay(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    dtFile.Load(reader);
    if (dtFile.Rows.Count > 0)
    {   
        FileTableView.DataSource = dtFile;
        FileTableView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Delete button

```
protected void File_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string command = e.CommandName;
    MBFile file;

    switch (command)
    {
        case "ShowPopup":
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Running");
            long fileid = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FileID: " + fileid);
            file = MBFile.RetrieveFile(Context.User.Identity.Name, fileid);
            LblFileID.Text = fileid.ToString();
            LblFileName.Text = file.fileName;
            LblFileType.Text = file.fileType;
            LblFileSize.Text = file.fileSize.ToString();

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myModal", "showPopup();", true);
            break;

        case "Delete":
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Deleting");
            MBFile.DeleteFile(Context.User.Identity.Name, Convert.ToInt64(LblFileID.Text));               
            FillDataFile();
            break;

        case "Download":
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Downloading");
            DownloadFileContent(Context.User.Identity.Name, Convert.ToInt64(LblFileID.Text));
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Delete Status", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + "File has been deleted" + "')</script>");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have just one record and deleted that record?

Comment: DataTable dtFile;    (the line above page_load) is that referenced anywhere else other than in the FillDataFile()  method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside FillDataFile there is this condition

```
if (dtFile.Rows.Count > 0)
{   
     FileTableView.DataSource = dtFile;
     FileTableView.DataBind();
}
```

If you have deleted the only one record present in the table then this condition prevents the rebind of your grid. In any case this condition is wrong per se. If you don't have records in the table you should bind the result anyway. Remove the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I am not properly getting about your question so below is my answer
If you want your grid view data update after delete then just add this line just after delete

```
YourGridView.DataSource = YourDataTable;
YourGridView.DataBind();
```

If you want your datatable to be update after delete then just add this line

```
YourDataTable.AcceptChanges();
```